# Trigonometry calculation

Tags: iphone, math, trigonometry

I assume this is would be a basic question however, my math skills are lacking.

I am working on an iphone game where people draw their own platform to bounce an egg up.

The game consists of a platform connecting 2 nodes each of these nodes has an x and y value this platform can be at any angle depending on how the user draws it,  when something hits this platform I need it to hit off perpendicularly.  I know how much total power I need, how would I break it down between X and Y.  I drew a picture to better explain...

[image: Two examples of my problem each for a different direction]

Here are two examples the info I have about the problem is the X & Y coordinate of the nodes, and the length of the dotted perpendicular line.  What I need to find is the length of the X and Y lines and if the X is going in a positive or negative direction.

Comment: The platform is the line connecting the two dots, right? It is fully defined by the two dots. Where is the "something" that hits it? What do you want to know?

Comment: You could calculate the slope of the nodes line, then use `-1 / slope` for being perpendicular. Using `y / x = -1 / slope` and Pythagoras' theorem, you can set up an equality with one variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two nodes, N1 and N2, and line length of L, then:

```
ndx = N1.x - N2.x
ndy = N1.y - N2.y
ndist = sqrt(ndx*ndx + ndy*ndy)
x = ndy * L / ndist
y = ndx * L / ndist
```

Comment: You might want to add this, since the player is probably going to want things to bounce "up" at all times:

    `x = y > 0 ? -x : x`
    `y = y > 0 ? -y : y`

Comment: Ahh yeah of course they are similar triangles ;) thankyou so very much

Answer (score 1):

If your two points are `A` and `B`, and the length of your line is `L`, you first need to find the angle `AB` makes with respect to the x-axis:

```
theta = atan( (B.x - A.x) / (B.y - A.y) )
```

Armed with this, you can figure out `x` and `y` thusly:

```
x = L * cos( theta )
y = L * sin( theta )
```

The only edge case you will have to consider is for a horizontal line (in which case the computation will fail because of divide by zero when calculating theta).  In the case of a horizontal line, `x=0` and `y=L`.

Comment: `theta = atan2( B.y - A.y, B.x - A.x )`, and you don't have to worry about the edge-cases.